# Powershell Scripting - Zipping, Moving BAK files to a new folder named for the date of BAK file creation

Tags: powershell, compression, 7zip

Firstly, Hello and apologies for the stupidly long title...

Secondly, I hope someone out there can help with what should be a simple task that has annoyed me for the past 4days, I will elaborate;

1. I have 4 x BAK file that are created between 22:30 and 23:00hrs each night.
2. Each BAK file is named differently and we append the date in format "yyyy_MM_dd".
3. I need to 7z each BAK file into separate archives and move them to a new directory either named for the date they where created or the appended date of the file but keep the format "yyyy_MM_dd". (Both will be the same obviously but the code will be different, so whichever is easiest)

I believe I have the separate lines for some of the script I need...

- For Creating the 7z

> dir *.bak | ForEach-Object { & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
>   a -t7z -mx3 ($*.Name+".7z") $*.Name }

- For Creating the folder

> $Folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path
>   "DRIVE2:\Folder1\Folder2\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"

- For Moving the files

> Get-ChildItem 'DRIVE1:\Folder1\Folder2\*.7z' | Copy-Item
>   -Destination $Folder

Can someone point out where I am being a complete nugget with this?

Thanks in advance

RobD

Answer (score 0):

If the files to copy are in DRIVE1:\Folder1\Folder2, then you are missing a slash between the folder and the wildcard.

```
Get-ChildItem 'DRIVE1:\Folder1\Folder2\*.7z' | Copy-Item -Destination $Folder
```

Comment: Edit 1 - My bad, thats poor re-typing, the slash is there.  Edit 2 - Whats also wierd is the slash is on the above when I edit but not when I save. Edit 3 - Put \\ in, now shows \...